# Why is my height of child element comes different in case of relative position and absolute position?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am confused. Both these the div takes up height 420px (70% of section's height) when  `position:relative` and takes up height:524px when `position:absolute`

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  border: 2px solid black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

div {
  height: 70%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning measures position relative to a fixed reference point, which is usually the size/position of a parent element. If an absolutely positioned element has no ancestor elements in the DOM with position "relative" or "absolute" (as is the case in your markup), it has nothing to use as a measuring reference so it defaults to positioning itself absolutely to the viewport (i.e , 70% of the viewport height instead of the content height)

Answer (score -1):

Give `div` height in px value.

```
height: 420px;
```